# correlation between time series and discrete time points

Tags: time-series, correlation

I have a time series of number of students crossing a street on a college campus on a working day. I also have the start times of classes (e.g., 8 am, 8:55 am, 9:50 am etc.) on that campus plotted as vertical reference lines on the plot. The time series has multiple peaks (high points or maxima) that appear to be aligned with the class start times (since students are getting to the classes around start of classes). Is there a way the correlation between the peaks of student numbers at the crossing and the class start times could be calculated ? Or in other words, can statistical evidence of class starts affecting the numbers of students on the crossing be shown ?

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the class starting and ending points $t_j$ into Gaussian kernels:$$x(t)=\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}d}\sum_j e^{-\frac{(t-t_j)^2}{2d^2}}$$

Now you can either look at the correlations of number of students $n_t$ with $x_t$, time series regression $$n_t=c+\beta x_t+\varepsilon_t$$ or time series analysis such as simple regression with AR(1) errors: $$n_t=c+\beta x_t+\varepsilon_t+\phi\varepsilon_{t-1}$$ then test significance of $\beta$

You pick an appropriate bandwidth $d$, such as 5 minutes or even tune it as a hyperparameter or do a nonlinear regression with it. Possibilities are endless.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My knowledge in statistics is very basic and I am not sure if I understand the solution you propose. Here are my questions. Why should we convert the time points into Gaussian kernels ? Why can't we regress for each class start, the number of minutes prior to class change and the number of students observed at each of those time instances instead ? Should the regression model for the entire duration of 12 hours. Is there any significance in assuming the number of students at a given instance is dependent on the error in the previous instance. Could you pl. clarify ?

Comment: I propose Gaussian kernels to account for the fact that the class start/end time likely to impact the traffic before and after the exact time. Students will be rushing to the class and from the class with different time proximity. So, the Gaussian kernel allows to correlate traffic in period $\approx\pm d$ to the schedule

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to understand why and how using Gaussian kernels and hyperparameters will be different from using linear regression models between lags & lead times in minutes from class starts and the number of students on the crosswalks. In such regression models, the beta corresponding to the explanatory variable becomes significant as I consider lag times 5 to 10 min around a given class start. If I include data corresponding to more distant lags, the beta becomes insignificant. Can you please help ? Will I be able to do Gaussian kernels and hyperparameter tuning in Python ?